# Which domain most appropriate for my users' experience?

Tags: web

I'm to go freelance (software developer) soon, and as part of that will be setting up my own domain. My domain will be my full name.

My two options so far are:

**firstnamesurname.co.uk**

or

**firstname-surname.com**

For somebody pursuing a professional image, I would've thought a .com as preferable, but the hyphen makes it seem a bit forced - and automatically becomes easier to forget.

Some further info:

I will not be working with anybody overseas (so .co.uk is still relevant enough).

This site will be visited mainly from links and references as opposed to the result of any SEO.

Comment: .com or .co.uk is fine, but if at all possible, avoid the hyphen as it will only cause you trouble... people will forget it, and go to someone else's site, and you will have to spell it out to everyone you meet.  Being able to say... just go to "Bob Jones dot com" or "Bob Jones dot co dot uk" will always work better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider surnamefirstname.com if it is available. The main difference I find between .com and local domain name are:

- .com : company could be established anywhere
- .co.uk : company established in the UK

.co.uk gives the message that the company is UK based. This could be beneficial for UK clients and other international clients who might want a UK based freelancer. When looking for other international clients this might not be as good if they want a more international company (as the .co.uk can imply there are no other offices).
.com on the other side has the characteristic that it is detached from the local aspect, which could be beneficial or not, depending on the case.

This being said, **as your intention is working as a freelancer for clients in the UK, I would say the .co.uk is better as it reinforces that you are UK based** and also the name is not using any character different than letters.

Comment: Nice answer but I don't think people are following this now a days. There are so many domains out there which are being used to fulfil the names only. E.g. .It, .Io, .Ng (specially with the words that can end with "ing") I really liked your answer but I feel like if you are getting a chance then you should go for .Com as there are keyboards shortcuts for that as well plus people are more familiar to that. Country specific domains are more for the firms and companies.